# sed only "search & replace"es a string that begins with "./" when run twice in a row

Tags: bash, sed

I want to use sed to strip the leading "./" from multiple strings in a bash script. I tried this:

```sh
search='\.\/'; replace=''; sed -i '' "s#$search#$replace#" ${MYVAR}/script.sh
```

but it didn't work. The command exited without errors, but the "./" was not removed.

***However***, running the same bash command twice in a row worked.

If anyone can help clear this up it would be really helpful, i.e. why the command fails when run once, but works when run twice in a row

Comment: How does it fail? What exactly happens when you run it once?

Comment: The command exits without errors, but the "./" has not been removed. I'll edit my question to mention that.

Comment: Can you show representative input and what it looks like after the first and second attempt?

Comment: Works for me. Demo: https://ideone.com/nC9BDY

Comment: Works for me too when using a string as input like in your example. Also works with a really minimal example file. Maybe there's something else in my script that's interfering somehow.

Comment: The command you're running only replaces the first occurrence on each line.  Try using the "global" flag on the sed substitute command.  `"s#$search#$replace#g"`

Comment: It works, thank you very much! Looks like the "g" fixed it.